# What material did you use to learn Flex/Air, and with ColdFusion + BlazeDS/LCDS?

Tags: apache-flex, coldfusion, air, blazeds, lcds

What material did you use to learn Flex/Air itself, and with ColdFusion + BlazeDS/LCDS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flex in a Week
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining/

FLEX tutorials PDF
http://henrylearnstorock.blogspot.com/2009/05/excellent-flex-tutorials-pdf.html

with CF:

Flex Workshop: Connecting Flex to ColdFusion
recording: http://experts.na3.acrobat.com/p45336977
The files necessary to follow along can be found here: http://www.iecfug.org/assets/content/resources/CF2FX.zip

CFMeetup:ColdFusion, LCDS, and Flex Magic: http://experts.na3.acrobat.com/p62931769/

http://www.horwith.com/index.cfm/2009/5/7/ColdFusion-Architecture-For-RIAs-Part-1

Answer (score 2):

We've got a section up on the Adobe Developer Center about using [Flex with ColdFusion](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex_cf.html) you can also check out some of the new features specifically for Flex and ColdFusion 9. I've got a [presentation here](http://slidesix.com/view/ColdFusion-9-and-Flex-4-Application-Development), and an [AdobeTV episode here](http://tv.adobe.com/#vi+f1472v1112).

=Ryan
ryan@adobe.com

Answer (score 1):

I personally used various blogs and books, but I have found these of interest:

[flexcf.com](http://www.flexcf.com/) : tutorials for flex and cf only.

[Flex/Coldfusion and Value Objects](http://tv.adobe.com/#vi+f15645v1037) presentation from 360 Flex 2008 in San Jose

In fact now I would just download [Adobe's Media Player](http://www.adobe.com/products/mediaplayer/) and search for MAX and 360 Flex and add both conferences to "my favorites".  They are from last year, however both contain solid material on flex 3 (with some flex 4), ColdFusion and/or BlazeDs.

In addition to that you might browse the Flex and Coldfusion Books on [Safari Books Online](http://www.safaribooksonline.com).  They have a free trial and a small bookshelf is rather affordable when compared to actually buying all those books.

Anyway those helped me alot.

**Edit**

It turns out you can only search the MAX sessions on AMP but you can "add content" and add the rss feed found [here](http://www.onflex.org/ted/2008/08/recording-360flex-free-full-sessions-on.php) for the 360 San Jose sessions.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.trajiklyhip.com/blog/index.cfm/2008/8/28/Integrating-BlazeDS-with-ColdFusion-8

Answer (score 0):

http://www.trajiklyhip.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/8/18/CFUnited-2009--My-AIR-Messaging-Slides-and-Code

Answer (score 0):

http://www.onflexwithcf.org/index.cfm/2007/8/2/Coldfusion-8-Simple-messaging-example-using-Messaging-Event-Gateway

New user 1 link at a time sorry about that.  But there 3 are helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Lynda.com training for ColdFusion and for Flex (beginner and advanced) by David Gassner is quite good.  I use them to refresh myself on current versions.  There's also Total Training for introductory Flex by James Talbot of Adobe, also very good, but I don't think it has an advanced tutorial.

I really enjoyed the book on Learning Flex 3 by Alaric Cole.  It reads very well and is not all dry.  I also liked Flex 3 for Dummies cowritten by by an Adobe Flex Engineer.  They complement eachother, and each has content lacking in the other.

Coming this fall, O'Reilly is releasing Enterprise Flex.  I've read some of the pre-release Rough Cut on Safari and found it basically teaches you how to hack or supercharge BlazeDS to have some of the advantages in the commercial product LCDS.

I don't believe there is any book or video tutorial for learning LCDS.  You have to read the documentation (I'd rather stick a fork in my eye, but I did it anyway).

HTH