# Blaze DS via Ajax with ColdFusion

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, coldfusion, blazeds

I want to use Adobe's Blaze DS via ColdFusion through Ajax. I know enough ColdFusion and JavaScript to do what I want to do, but I want to add long poling into the application and it looks like the only way to do that is through Blaze DS...but I don't know enough about Flash/Flex to finish the job. Anyone know of an Ajax Mockup that works?

Answer (score 0):

> Using the Flex Ajax Bridge
>
> The Adobe® Flex® Ajax Bridge
>   (FABridge) is a small, unobtrusive
>   code library that you can insert into
>   an Flex application, a Flex component,
>   or an empty SWF file to expose it to
>   scripting in the web browser.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/ajaxbridge_1.html

Comment: Any ideas on the ColdFusion side? I installed it but couldn't figure out how to verify if it was even running.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Flex as well.  You need to get the Flex side of things working first, then this ajax bridge will let your webpage to use Ajax to control an empty SWF that communicate with BlazeDS.  So this is not a totally SWF-free solution.

Comment: See if these links help to get you going: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395658/what-material-did-you-use-to-learn-flex-air-and-with-coldfusion-blazeds-lcds

Answer (score 0):

Just found out about this today.  Maybe easier than BlazeDS+Flex+Ajax?

http://www.ape-project.org/